# In how many ways can $8$ appointments be scheduled for a physician visiting a nursing home with $20$ patients?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A physician routinely visits a local nursing home on Thursday mornings to examine patients. Suppose the facility has $20$ residents, but the physician only has time to check $8$. The supervisor places $8$ random patients on an order list and presents the schedule to the physician.

a. How many different schedules are possible? 
b. If there are $15$ women and $5$ men in the facility, what is the probability that all appointments will be with women?

All the help is much appreciated. Also, if you can explain how you got the answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Comment: An "order list" suggests that the sequence of patients on the "schedule" matters in terms of counting outcomes.  Does this suggest an approach to part (a)?  For part (b) (the probability all scheduled patients will be women), the order does *not* make a difference.